# change sidebar or just widgets for 2 specific post type single posts

Tags: sidebar

I would like to show a different sidebar for 2 specific posts(same custom post type). I understand how to do this using separate templates for different pages, but I want to have it all happen in the single-posttype.php page. Or am I thinking about this wrong? My end goal is to show different text widgets in the sidebar on specific posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) is what you're looking for. It adds a field to each widget to allow you to specify which post get which widgets. It uses the standard [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) making it easy to use.  You'd just want to do something like

```
is_single( 'Slug1-or-ID1' ) ||  is_single( 'Slug2-or-ID2' )
```

You could also try the [a post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type) method to show only a specific post type:

```
//not tested but something like     
global $post; return ('book' == get_post_type($post));
```

Comment: I did find  Widget Logic through another post and tried it, but found the documentation lacking and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: humm... works gret for me. What's your experiance level with PHP? Also, did you try it with the snippit I posted above?

Comment: I tried it with `is_single( '96' )` id of post. I am not adept with PHP, and that didn't work. I don't get what to do with the last suggestion about the post type.

Comment: Humm.. works like a charm for me. It could be a theme related issue though. For example if your theme is overwriting your widgets.

Comment: To be sure that there is no theme problem try Widget Logic approach on default theme (Twenty Eleven).

Comment: You were right Widget logic is the answer. i just needed to tick `'wp_reset_query'` to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A separate approach would be to register multiple sidebars, and then call each one conditionally. e.g.

Register sidebars:

```
// Registers Primary Widget Area
register_sidebar(
    array (
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar',
        'description' => __'Primary sidebar widget area',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) 
);
// Registers Primary Widget Area
register_sidebar(
    array (
        'name' => '{Post Type} Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar-{post-type}',
        'description' => __'{Post Type} sidebar widget area',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) 
);
```

(Note: replace `{post-type}` with the actual name/slug of your CPT, as appropriate.)

Then, in your template file:

```
$sidebar_id = ( 'custom-post-type-slug' == get_post_type() ? 'sidebar-{post-type}' : 'sidebar' );

dynamic_sidebar ( $sidebar_id );
```

So, you won't need to create separate template files for your CPT; however, you will have two separate Widget areas appear in `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets`, that you will have to populate separately.

**EDIT**

How are you *displaying* your CPTs?

If you're using `archive-{post-type}.php` and `single-{post-type}.php`, then you can simply call `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-{post-type}' )` (or whatever you named it when you registered it) in those template files.

Otherwise, if you're using the normal `archive.php` and `single.php` to display your CPTs, then use the conditional code I originally suggested.

Comment: I already registered the sidebars, so I think your approach is what I was looking for. Let you know how it works.

Comment: Chip, which part of this is telling Wp to show the sidebar for the particular post? When you refer to `replace {post-type} with the actual name/slug` are you talking about the post type itself or the individual post slug?

Comment: @Drai Chip's method only will display different sidebar for your CPT

Comment: What did you name the Sidebar for your CPT? Use that in place of `sidebar-{post_type}`.

Comment: I wanted a different sidebar for different specific posts within CPT. Like if post('1') show this sidebar1 else if post('2') show sidebar2. If that's not possible should I be looking at the hide/show widget suggestions?

Comment: See answer edit. How are you *displaying* your CPTs? Are you using the standard template files, or are you using CPT-specific template files?

Comment: Hey @ChipBennett - how would you use this method to target specific CPT posts? eg. A custom post type name "Artists" exists...each artist has a post that essentially acts as their artist page. Upon visiting their page, (single-artists.php) - how would you specifically show a different sidebar for each single post page within that CPT??? Ive been struggling with this for some time now.

Comment: @Mr.Brown in that case, just use Widget Logic.

Comment: Is Widget Logic the only way? This is for a client who will not understand how to input conditional tags into widgets, etc. I would prefer to hardcode it in if at all possible...Or am I misunderstanding how the Widget Logic plugin works?

Comment: Hard-coding is possible, but extremely fragile. If you know the Post ID, and **know** that the Post ID won't change, then you can use `global $post; $post->ID` in a conditional.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, thats no good Im sure they will change things on their own eventually and then the site will break. I wonder when Wordpress will begin to support a more diverse selection of templates for CPT's?

Comment: What "more diverse selection of templates of CPTs" are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin for this! There's a filter called 'sidebars_widgets' defined in one of the core files, which will allow you to achieve this very easily! I have written a simple tutorial on how to do it. [Show/hide widgets on specific pages](http://blog.rutwick.com/show-or-hide-a-wp-widget-only-on-specific-pages). Check the example there, look for the line:

```
if(is_front_page() || is_home())
```

and replace it with

```
if(is_singular('posttype'))
```

That's it!
Hope it helps!

Comment: You don't NEED a plugin for anything really. However, plugins often make things way simpler. I COULD add 20 lines or so to my themes functions.php OR just install a plugin and let it do the work saving myself time and a headache.

Comment: interesting. I think I prefer the switching sidebar solution, but good to know.

Comment: @Drai Sure. I believe in having a total control over my code (and if the task is easy), hence I used the filter. Anyways, good luck with whatever works for you! :)